# Receiving a float as 4 individual bytes then converting it back

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving via UDP, 4 byte packets that represent what was a float (from C# code). I now need to turn these bytes back into the single so it's the same number as it was before

I've done a bit of trial and error but I'm not even close to turning it into a single accurately. All I do know is that the number is between 0 and 1, and is in little-endian format.

A few more things that may help

> When the float is 1
> Byte(0) = 0, Byte(1) = 0, Byte(2) = 128, Byte(3) = 63
>
> When the float is approximately 0.5
> Byte(0) = 234, Byte(1) = 111, Byte(2) = 247, Byte(3) = 62
>
> When the float is approximately 0.75
> Byte(0) = 178, Byte(1) = 56, Byte(2) = 64, Byte(3) = 63

Comment: The [BitConverter.ToSingle Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=netframework-4.8) does what you want. (The values are 1, 0.4832757, 0.7508651.)

Comment: yep that is exactly what i was looking for thank you